# Is there any other way to extract the optional without forcing it?

Tags: swift, function, option-type

I need to extract the optional without "!" inside the function:

```
func arrayFunc1(array1: [Int]) -> Int? {
    let number1 = array1.first
    let number2 = array1.last
    guard array1.count < 2 else {
        return number1! + number2! // it works with "!" but it doesn't work without it
    }
    return nil
}

print(arrayFunc1(array1: [1, 2]))
```

can I use any other way? if I remove "!" it says I can't use "Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'Int?' operands"

Comment: That's not the entirety of `arrayFunc1`, is it? You still have more code after the `guard`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you bind with a `let number1 = ...` in a `guard` clause is not going to be available inside the `else` of that guard. Rather, they are only available *after* the guard statement. So you can't bind `number1` and `number2` and then return them in the `else` branch of the same guard statement.

You can go for an `if` instead, checking the opposite condition of `count >= 2`:

```
if array1.count >= 2, let number1 = array1.first, let number2 = array1.last {
    return number1 + number2
} else {
    // if you were planning on using number1 and number2 here, you 
    // should use array1.first and .last instead
    return nil
}
```

I'm not sure what you are planning on doing in the `return nil` case, but if you are going to use `number1` and `number2`, you should use `array1.first` and `array2.last`. Note that these are of type `Int?`, just like in your original code. After all, there is the possibility that the array could be empty!

If you want to handle the empty case too, you can do:

```
guard let number1 = array1.first, let number2 = array1.last else {
    return nil // or whatever else you want to do if the array is empty
}
guard array1.count < 2 else {
    return number1 + number2
}
// I'm guessing you're going to use number1 and number2 somehow,
// and want them to be non nullable Ints?
return nil
```

But then your function only works with 1-element and 2-element arrays. You might just want to take in two `Int` parameters, with the second being optional:

```
func someFunc(int1: Int, int2: Int? = nil) -> Int {
```